# WSL in Windows Container

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to use Bash for Windows (Windows subsystem for Linux) inside of a Windows Docker Container.

Use Case: I have a Windows application (which I want to dockerize), which also needs to run certain Linux commands.

I've tried to create an image with WSL enabled:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Enable Developer Mode
RUN New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" -ItemType Directory -Force
RUN New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" -Name AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense -PropertyType DWORD -Value 1

# Enable WSL
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux -Online -All -NoRestart
```

But it fails with `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is unknown.`

*Question*: Is this even technically possible? If yes, how would I write the Dockerfile?

Comment: WSL isn't supported on *Server*, only on the desktop. That's coming soon. Since you *are* using experimental features, use a base image that targets the latest Fast Ring build. It doesn't require Developer Mode

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis. Makes sense. Fast Ring images of Windows Server aren't on hub.docker.com, right? Do you have an idea where to find these?

Comment: You make them yourself. Although *coming soon*. Server support was [announced](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2017/05/10/windows-server-for-developers-news-from-microsoft-build-2017/) only 1 month ago. It's not available yet. Until it is, use a Windows 10 base image